# Stock with sending data with jQuery to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data via POST to PHP file..
$.get() - works fine, hovewer I couldn't tell the same about $.post() or $.ajax() with method post.. 
Here my code I wrote:

```
$('[name="update"]').click(function(){
    tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    u = [];
    u["username"] = tr.find('[name="u[username]"]').val();
    u["display_name"] = tr.find('[name="u[display_name]"]').val();
    u["type"] = tr.find('[name="u[type]"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax-queries/update-user.php",
        data: {update:u},
        cache: false,
        success:  function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
     });

});
```

And PHP file looks like:

```
<?php 
     print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Response I get:

```
Array(
)
```

Using latest jQuery lib... no ideas why not working.. any solutions you can offer?
Is that could be posible because of port:2014?
in case i tried and in :80 (same results)..

Comment: Are you sure that `url: "../ajax-queries/update-user.php",` is correct? I remind you that you must take into consideration the path where the PAGE where you add this `<script>` jquery file is and NOT where your jquery folder is when contructing the url parametre.

Comment: Yeah, I had good dir, in case I wouldn't get an empty Array() response :) however your offer might will help to others someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't setting anything. 
Try changing **u** to `{}`, like: `u = {};`

Comment: Worked after I tried 
data:{update:u["..."]}, anyways.. is there a way to send an array?

Comment: are you sure ? try clear browser cache ... maybe the changes at the code aren't take effect (because it's cached.)

Comment: Worked! How I forgot about that.. THank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Array with key index is not an array, it's an object, try alert(typeof u).
sending an array with key index will fail in IE8.